# Invalidate List SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

#### Workaround at bottom of Question

I thought SwiftUI was supposed to automatically update views when data they were dependent on changed. However that isn't happening in the code below:

First I make a simple `BindableObject`

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Example: BindableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    
    var test = 1 {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(())
        }
    }
}
```

Then the root view of the app:

```
struct BindTest : View {
    @Binding var test: Example
    var body: some View {
        PresentationButton(destination: BindChange(test: $test)) {
            ForEach(0..<test.test) { index in
                Text("Invalidate Me! \(index)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the view in which I change the value of the `BindableObject`:

```
struct BindChange : View {
    @Binding var test: Example
    @Environment(\.isPresented) var isPresented
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: act) {
            Text("Return")
        }
    }
    
    func act() {
        test.test = 2
        isPresented?.value = false
    }
}
```

When the return button is tapped there should be 2 instances of the Text View - but there is only 1. What am I doing wrong?

Also worth noting: If I change the `@Binding` to `@EnvironmentObject` the program just crashes when you tap the button producing this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Full code below:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Example: BindableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Example, Never>()
    
    var test = 1 {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    
    static let `default` = {
        return Example()
    }()
}
//Root View
struct BindTest : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var test: Example
    var body: some View {
        PresentationButton(destination: BindChange()) {
            ForEach(0..<test.test) { t in
                Text("Invalidate Me! \(t)")
            }
        }
    }
}
//View that changes the value of @Binding / @EnvironmentObject
struct BindChange : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var test: Example
    @Environment(\.isPresented) var isPresented
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: act) {
            Text("Return")
        }
    }
    
    func act() {
        test.test = 2
        isPresented?.value = false
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        //ContentView().environmentObject(EntryStore())
        BindTest().environmentObject(Example())
    }
}
#endif
```

EDIT 2: Post's getting a little messy at this point but the crash with `EnvironmentObject` seems to be related to an issue with `PresentationButton`

By putting a NavigationButton inside a NavigationView the following code produces the correct result - invalidating the `List` when `test.test` changes:

```
//Root View
struct BindTest : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var test: Example
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationButton(destination: BindChange()) {
                ForEach(0..<test.test) { t in
                    Text("Functional Button #\(t)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `BindTest` is the root view of the app, then why is `test` a `@Binding var`? Are you passing `test` through the initializer of `BindTest` from somewhere else?

Comment: I wrote the code specifically for the question as the production code is extremely unorganized (but yeah, the names are bad point taken) For the actual use case: I have one view (analogous to `BindTest`) where I display a list of places in my Core Data model. Then there is a navigation button that presents another view (analogous to `BindChange`) where the user can filter the list based on distance from current location. The filter works (array count is reduced) but when the filterView is dismissed all the cities are still present.

Comment: @graycampbell yes, in this example I pass it as a `.constant(.default)` in the `PreviewProvider` in production I pass it to the root view in the SceneDelegate

Comment: Where is it not working? In your preview or in production?

Comment: Neither is working

Comment: Are you passing `.constant(.default)` in both cases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196431/discussion-between-graycampbell-and-brandon-bradley).

Comment: No just in the above example. In production the Core Data Store is called in the SceneDelegate and passed to the root view